# An algorithmic question concerning shortest paths and such

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a very, very large graph, and I want to find the shortest path from one vertex to another. The graph is directed and unweighted.

I have considered using some modification of Dijkstra's algorithm, but I usually use that for weighted undirected graphs.

So then my other thought was to use a DFS, since I can treat all the weights as one.

Any suggestions? a

EDIT: Ok, I meant to say BFS, I'm sorry.

Comment: Approximately how many nodes do you have and how many edges?

Comment: I do not recommend DFS: http://xkcd.com/761/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) instead.

(Note that Dijkstra's algorithm works perfectly fine for unweighted directed graphs — it just happens that in the unweighted case, doing it smartly is essentially equivalent to a breadth-first search.)

Comment: I've merged the comment from my answer into this and deleted mine; feel free to remove the comment if you (don't) like. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)?

Comment: There is absolutely no point using A* here with an unweighted graph… it would do nothing better than a breadth-first search, and possibly take more time (unless you do it properly, in which case it *is* a breadth-first search).